# How to prevent . (full stop) from being awkwardly separated by a space (while using spacy)

Tags: python, split, spacy

When using the [spacy](https://spacy.io/) If you wish to join a list of words into a sentence. You do the following

```
import spacy

def join_words(word):
    nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
    doc = nlp(" ".join(word))
    return doc.text

if __name__ == "__main__":
    word_list = ["She", "walks", "to", "the", "store", "and", "buys", "some", "fruits."]

    # Join the list of words into a sentence
    sentence = join_words(word_list)

    print(f"Joined, {sentence}")
```

The Output you receive for the above code is rather unpleasant from a language standpoint.

Output:
`She walks to the store and buys some fruits .`

Where the fullstop is given a separate place of its own,I am looking for a way to try to make sure such mistakes don't occur and the it comes out like this - `She walks to the store and buys some fruits.`